# Create a makefile for Unix

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I have only one file: main.cpp and I want to create a `makefile` in order to run it via `Unix`..
I am trying to write a `makefile`, so in my `makefile` I wrote:

```
#file: makefile

a.out : main.o
        g++ main.o -ansi -pedantic‬

main.o : main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -ansi -pedantic‬

clean : rm main.o a.out
```

it's ok? how can I run it?

```
makefile
a.out
```

Comment: Run `make a.out`, although you need a `-c` option when cimpiling `main.o`: `g++ -c main.cpp -ansi -pedantic`

Comment: something like:

#file: makefile

a.out : main.o
        g++ main.o -ansi -pedantic‬

main.o : main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp -ansi -pedantic‬

clean : rm main.o a.out, right? thank you!

Comment: That looks right. Without the `-c` flag, `g++` tries to compile an executable, but you want a shared object (main.o). Also, `make` requires tabs, I think one of the answers states that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read an introductory make tutorial. You need to read at least the basics.

http://capone.mtsu.edu/csdept/FacilitiesAndResources/make.htm

The GNU make has a complete (but harder to read) manual too:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

About your specific example: you run make to generate a.out. Then, you can run a.out:

```
$ make
$ ./a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

If `main.cpp` is the only source file, you probably don't even need a Makefile.

```
$ rm Makefile
$ make main
```

Make has very reasonable default rules.  Take advantage of them.  (The above
will work with some flavors of Make, but (probably) not all.)